# Python get difference of the two datetime strings

Tags: python, list, variables, countdown

Okay, so, I'm new to Python (this is my first program).  I'm trying to make a countdown timer that counts down to any given date.  I have some (simple) parts that work, and my next step questions include: Do I need to store the given time in a list, then parse through it and store the year, the day, etc. in separate variables?  Can I subtract one date for another in Python to give me an amount of time left?

## STORE CURRENT TIME IN A VARIABLE.

```
from datetime import datetime
current_time = (str(datetime.now()))
print("The current time is " + current_time)
```

## Store target time in a variable

```
target_day = input("What date are you waiting for (day/month/year format, please)?")
```

## something like

```
time_left = target_time - current_time
```

## OR

```
while current_time:
    if current_time == target time:
        break
    print("It's time!")

print(\rtime_left)
print("You have " + weeks + "weeks, " + days + "days," + hours + "hours, and " + minutes.")
```

Comment: As a hint, lookup [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) in the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object of the both the times and subtract both the object to get the object of the [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) type. Then call the [`total_seconds(..)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) function of the *timedelta* object to get the time difference in seconds. For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> target_time = '18/03/2022'

>>> target_datetime = datetime.strptime(target_time, '%M/%d/%Y')
>>> current_datetime = datetime.now() # No need to convert it to string

>>> time_left = target_datetime - current_datetime # return `timedelta` object



# returns total seconds 
>>> time_left.total_seconds()
139037207.03403
```

Answer (score 0):

> time_left = target_time - current_time

You are very close. What's frustrating you is that you still need to convert target_time, a str, to a datetime. Then you'll get a timedelta result from the subtraction, which you'll find very useful. Parse a date with this [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
target_time = datetime.strptime(text_from_user, '%d-%b-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is print out the difference between the time you are waiting for and the time now. This is can be done easily by simple subtraction by converting everything into seconds and then subtracting to get the seconds without any carry overs. Next just convert the seconds into years, months, days, minutes, and seconds again by just using a loop to first divide (mod) the seconds by 60 and getting the remainder as seconds and then dividing the minutes by 60 with the remainder as minutes again, then divide by 24 to get the remainder as hours and so on...

Also, I would recommend setting an interval otherwise your program will just keep printing the same date as fast as it can before moving on, rather you could set an interval otherwise your loop will just keep checking itself and printing you have "this long left" more times than it needs to.

Of course there are easier ways, this is just to explain in detail the steps taken to do it manually to help you understand rather than just paste in a line without understanding it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `datetime` module can do that without converting everything yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I just said all of this to hopefully improve the understanding of it.